# How to make SVG Stabius-Werner projection

Tags: coordinate-system, svg

I'd like to create a SVG file of a [Stabius-Werner projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_projection) of the Earth.

The image in the linked page is nice in that it's very high resolution (2,058 x 2,065 pixels), but I'd like to see if I can get at least the line information (if not all the land detail which I know probably needs to be raster-based rather than vector-based) like the latitude and longitude lines to be vector-based.

The [description of the image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWerner_projection_SW.jpg) mentions that it was "...created with the Geocart map projection software" and reading the user manual it looks like Geocart could export vector files, but the application is very pricey.

What are some other ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

you could use the program MicroCAM (free), export to hpgl Plot-File and afterwards import into Inkscape. I have uploaded an example here: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stabwerner.svg

Download-Link for MicroCAM:
http://www.csiss.org/map-projections/microcam/

additional info:
As http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stab-Wernersche_Projektion explains, the Stabius-Werner is a Bonne-Projection with a standard-parallel 90 degree north.

there is a bonne90.cam example file included with the microCam distribution

update: you can download also this pdf-map http://www.csiss.org/map-projections/Pseudoconic/Stab_Werner.pdf and import into inkscape

update2: if a high-resolution, high-quality raster map,which you can import into your svg-file, also fits your needs, I recommend the free program g.projector, which you can download here:
http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/